# JMeter - Iterate the Remote Commands over a csv file

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

I need to simulate the below via JMeter:

```
1. Launch Putty.
2. Enter the IP Address.
3. Login
4. Execute a command. This command needs to be iterated over a csv file.
```

Unsure of point number 4. especially the iterating part.

Please help.

Regards,
Ajith

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `Execute a command` - take a look at [OS Process Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-external-commands-and-programs-locally-and-remotely-jmeter)
- `This command needs to be iterated over a csv file` - take a look at [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config)

If you CSV file looks like:

```
command1
command2
command3
```

The following CSV Data Set Config setup:

[image]

will read the command from the file and save it to `${command}` JMeter Variable, the variable will be updated for next iteration of next thread (virtual user)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `beanshell sampler` to run commands from your native terminal. Beanshell is just java. You can write all your java code to open a terminal to run your commands. To read data from csv you can use jemetr `CSV Data set config`.

Sample test.csv file:

```
a,b,c
x,y,z
p,q,r
```

Sample beanshell commands to show how you can read data from csv to parametrize your commands: ${a} and vars.get("b") both will work.

```
log.info("${a} - - - - "+vars.get("b"));
```

Demo jmx file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jmeterTestPlan version="1.2" properties="5.0" jmeter="5.0 r1840935">
  <hashTree>
    <TestPlan guiclass="TestPlanGui" testclass="TestPlan" testname="Test Plan" enabled="true">
      <stringProp name="TestPlan.comments"></stringProp>
      <boolProp name="TestPlan.functional_mode">false</boolProp>
      <boolProp name="TestPlan.tearDown_on_shutdown">true</boolProp>
      <boolProp name="TestPlan.serialize_threadgroups">false</boolProp>
      <elementProp name="TestPlan.user_defined_variables" elementType="Arguments" guiclass="ArgumentsPanel" testclass="Arguments" testname="User Defined Variables" enabled="true">
        <collectionProp name="Arguments.arguments"/>
      </elementProp>
      <stringProp name="TestPlan.user_define_classpath"></stringProp>
    </TestPlan>
    <hashTree>
      <ThreadGroup guiclass="ThreadGroupGui" testclass="ThreadGroup" testname="Thread Group" enabled="true">
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.on_sample_error">continue</stringProp>
        <elementProp name="ThreadGroup.main_controller" elementType="LoopController" guiclass="LoopControlPanel" testclass="LoopController" testname="Loop Controller" enabled="true">
          <boolProp name="LoopController.continue_forever">false</boolProp>
          <stringProp name="LoopController.loops">1</stringProp>
        </elementProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.num_threads">10</stringProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.ramp_time">1</stringProp>
        <boolProp name="ThreadGroup.scheduler">false</boolProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.duration"></stringProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.delay"></stringProp>
      </ThreadGroup>
      <hashTree>
        <BeanShellSampler guiclass="BeanShellSamplerGui" testclass="BeanShellSampler" testname="BeanShell Sampler" enabled="true">
          <stringProp name="BeanShellSampler.query">log.info(&quot;${a} - - - - &quot;+vars.get(&quot;b&quot;));
log.info(&quot;qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq&quot;);</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="BeanShellSampler.filename"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="BeanShellSampler.parameters"></stringProp>
          <boolProp name="BeanShellSampler.resetInterpreter">false</boolProp>
        </BeanShellSampler>
        <hashTree/>
        <ResultCollector guiclass="ViewResultsFullVisualizer" testclass="ResultCollector" testname="View Results Tree" enabled="true">
          <boolProp name="ResultCollector.error_logging">false</boolProp>
          <objProp>
            <name>saveConfig</name>
            <value class="SampleSaveConfiguration">
              <time>true</time>
              <latency>true</latency>
              <timestamp>true</timestamp>
              <success>true</success>
              <label>true</label>
              <code>true</code>
              <message>true</message>
              <threadName>true</threadName>
              <dataType>true</dataType>
              <encoding>false</encoding>
              <assertions>true</assertions>
              <subresults>true</subresults>
              <responseData>false</responseData>
              <samplerData>false</samplerData>
              <xml>false</xml>
              <fieldNames>true</fieldNames>
              <responseHeaders>false</responseHeaders>
              <requestHeaders>false</requestHeaders>
              <responseDataOnError>false</responseDataOnError>
              <saveAssertionResultsFailureMessage>true</saveAssertionResultsFailureMessage>
              <assertionsResultsToSave>0</assertionsResultsToSave>
              <bytes>true</bytes>
              <sentBytes>true</sentBytes>
              <url>true</url>
              <threadCounts>true</threadCounts>
              <idleTime>true</idleTime>
              <connectTime>true</connectTime>
            </value>
          </objProp>
          <stringProp name="filename"></stringProp>
        </ResultCollector>
        <hashTree/>
      </hashTree>
      <CSVDataSet guiclass="TestBeanGUI" testclass="CSVDataSet" testname="CSV Data Set Config" enabled="true">
        <stringProp name="delimiter">,</stringProp>
        <stringProp name="fileEncoding">UTF-8</stringProp>
        <stringProp name="filename">C:/Users/sushilgupta/Downloads/test.csv</stringProp>
        <boolProp name="ignoreFirstLine">false</boolProp>
        <boolProp name="quotedData">false</boolProp>
        <boolProp name="recycle">true</boolProp>
        <stringProp name="shareMode">shareMode.all</stringProp>
        <boolProp name="stopThread">false</boolProp>
        <stringProp name="variableNames">a,b,c</stringProp>
      </CSVDataSet>
      <hashTree/>
    </hashTree>
  </hashTree>
</jmeterTestPlan>
```

You can also use selenium autoit to run your commands as manual simulation with selenium web driver plugin.